# C3.js drawing lines between two different columns or data series

Tags: c3.js

I have three time series which are plotted on the same graph using null values so that only one series is displayed for any one time, basically to get different colouring for rising and falling points.

Does anyone know how I can link the points together with lines even though they are from different series?  I know with a bar chart you can use a group feature for different series to have them display on top of each other, however this doesn't seem to work for line.  Here is a picture of the unconnected dots:
[image: un-connected dots]

Comment: Willing to have a go if you can post your c3 create code and some sample plot data.

Comment: I think you could pre-process the data into separate rising-falling series then C3 would do it all for you. You would want to switch off some of the legend entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you present the data to C3 as separate series with nulls where the series should not plot, then you get something like your required affect. In this snippet I have used two series - you would want a series per rising and falling set of points.

```js
var chart = c3.generate(
{
    bindto: '#chart',
    size: {
      width: 600,
      height: 180
    },
  data: {
    x: 'xLabels',
    columns: [
      ['xLabels', '2015-09-17 00:00:00','2015-09-18 00:00:00','2015-09-19 00:00:00','2015-09-20 00:00:00','2015-09-21 00:00:00','2015-09-22 00:00:00','2015-09-23 00:00:00','2015-09-24 00:00:00'],
     ['data1', 5,10,12,17,null,null,null,null],
     ['data2', null,null,null,null,17,13,12,11],
     ['data3', null,null,null,17,17,null,null,null],
    ],
    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', // ### IMPORTANT - this is how d3 understands the date formatted in the xLabels array 
    types: {
      'data1': 'area-spline',
      'data2': 'area-spline',
      'data3': 'line'
    },
  colors: {
     data3: '#cccccc'
    }    
  },
  point: {
    show: true    
  },
  legend: {
      position: 'inset',
  inset: {
      anchor: 'top-left',
      x: 20,
      y: 10,
      step: 2
    }
  },
  axis: {
    y: {
      tick: {
        format: function (d) { return d + "%"; }
      }
    },
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        format: '%Y-%m-%d'  // how the date is displayed
      }
    }
  }, 
  tooltip:{
    format:{
      title:function (x) { return x.getDate() + "/" + x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getFullYear() + " " + x.getHours()+ ":" + x.getMinutes() },
    }
  }  
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.js"></script>

<div class='chart-wrapper'>
<div class='chat' id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello good sir thank you very much for doing that, sorry I got distracted for a few days and am only just now coming back to this.  So I have done the above and the question is - is it possible to get the 2015-09-20 17% and the 2015-09-21 17% points connected somehow?  So its a continuous line with no gaps?

Comment: Hi - I have modified my snippet to include a third data series which spans the gap between the initial two. However, this third connector line does not 'slow' from with the area splines because it had no knowledge of the plot points that give the spline curves. I also tried a to give the third series a full set of plot points so as to make it aware of this but this results in a gap between the curve of this third date line and the other two regions. I cannot find a solution for pure region-coloring  where you change the colours of area regions.